# Flash objects Hierarchie

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, object, instance

here is a simple concept kind of question about the objects and instances in flash:

lets say i have a leg library object, which is then used in another object to create a human, and the the human is used on the main project stage. If, on the main project stage, in a separate actions layer, I add a collision event with the leg, would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You would target the leg.

```
if (human1.leg1.hitTestObject(theOtherObject)) {
trace("hit");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it would work depending on how you do the collision. If you want it to do collision for the body first, and then the leg, it likely will not work. But if you try to do collision only for the leg and other parts individually, then you should be able to get it to work.